# Change Label Text during long Code Behind Process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have `Label` And `Button` In One `UpdatePanel` ,Now I call Long Process with `ForEach` Loop `On Button Click` What I want is to Update Text Of `Label` after Completion Of Loop.Is there any Easy Way to Change Text Of `Label` At runtime.I heard Something that we can do this with `Iframe` But I dont have any idea about that.

**CODE**

**aspx**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelUpdate" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">     <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
        onclick="ButtonUpdate_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
   <asp:Label ID="LabelUpdateCount" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    < /div>
   </ContentTemplate>

   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
    protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int count = 0;
    foreach()
    {
        do my stuff();
        count = count + 1;
        LabelUpdateCount.Text = count.ToString();


    }
}
```

SO,I want to show change of label at runtime.....

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, the server returns only after the method is completed but you want the client side label to display the current completed item count while it’s being done.

I would like to mentions an issue with it. Each post back will take roughly around 200-400ms so it won’t be updated any sooner. I strongly suggest consider updating every once in a while than trying to update for every job completed.

To accomplish this you have to run your function loop on a different thread (have it modify a variable). Add have the client check its status using js timer(return the value of the variable).

In other words what you are trying to do is to show progress to the client. In which case the following link might be useful.

[Real-Time Progress Bar With ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Note: it returns percentage. You can change it such a way to have it return the count.

The above link is taken from the below question. It is in many ways related issue.

[ASP.NET AJAX Progress Bar: Update from Code Behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/798235/1170610)

Answer (score 0):

```
MyLabel.Text = "The process has completed.";
```

Just ensure that this label is also included inside the update panel, and it should update when the process has completed on the server side and returned to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple.

Example:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var a in loopItems)
    {
        DoMyWork(a);
    }

    label1.Text = "Complete";
}
```

Comment: It Shows Only After process Complete I want to show it at runtime

Comment: What do you mean you want to show it?  The text should be visible in the label as soon as the method is completed.  As long as you have it in the same update panel as the button.

Comment: Yes You are right on that ,text will be visible as soon as method completed,I want to change label and show it at runtime

Comment: Is the label visible?  If not, can you call `label1.Visible = true;`?